# Is there a way to change a Dock launcher config?

Tags: gnome, launcher, configuration, dock

I run VS-code and did "*Add to favorites*" to start it easily.

However, I also need to have the `-disable-gpu`option, otherwise VS-code hangs forever.

But doing "*Add to favorites*" Gnome did only save the Exec path, not the options that were accompanying it.

Is there a way to change the Dock launcher to add this parameter?

In other words, is there a Dock Launchers config available somewhere that allows that kind of change?  (didn't see it in *dconf*)

<sub>NB I know it's possible to create a new *.desktop* file, then "run/start" it, then *Add to favorites*. My questions aims directly at the Dock config. Thanks</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Question still opened, but this is what I found so far:

- doing `dconf dump / > a`
- then doing a dock operation, like removing a favorite
- doing `dconf dump / > b`

A `diff a b` tells me that this line

```
favorite-apps=['org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', ..., 'code.desktop']
```

changed.

So I did a `find ~ -name code.desktop` and, surprise, nothing. Did the same *find* but from `/`...

and...

```
$ ll /usr/share/applications/code.desktop
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 513 May  3 03:45 /usr/share/applications/code.desktop*
```

It's in `/usr/share/applications`, of course, where user desktop apps are. The dock simply uses the default .desktop file installed by dpkg.

I changed the file directly, but one might prefer to copy the .desktop file to `~/.local/share/applications` and make changes here.

Comment: Was just preparing an answer, but you found the correct answer yourself. Indeed, it is good you added the comment on working on a local copy: files under /usr/share are managed by the APT system and can be overwritten anytime. Neat though convoluted trick you used to find the desktop file ;)